# storm.yaml parsing error when running "bin/storm nimbus"

Tags: apache-storm

I am trying to setup a 3 node cluster (nimbus/supervisor/supervisor), but my `conf/storm.yaml` file cannot be parsed when running `bin/storm nimbus`.

conf/storm.yaml:

```
storm.zookeeper.servers:
  - "192.168.1.202"
  - "192.168.1.203"
  - "192.168.1.204"
storm.local.dir: "/opt/storm-1.2.1”
nimbus.seeds: ["192.168.1.202"]
supervisor.slots.ports:
  - 6700
  - 6701
  - 6702
  - 6703
storm.health.check.dir: "healthchecks"
storm.health.check.timeout.ms: 5000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a special quotation mark at the end of

```
storm.local.dir: "/opt/storm-1.2.1”
```

You can validate your yaml with e.g. http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/